# Comparing Equations to find optimum point

Tags: optimization

If I have 2 or more eqiations of degree 5, each representing a parametrr that I'd want to optimie. Say, one equation shows trend of production and the other one trend of rejections and both are function of $x$. 
Now I need a value of $x$ at which my system is optimized.

Meaning a value of $x$ for which production is maximized and rejection is minimized? Your answers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\exists x_0  | f'(x_0) = 0 \land g'(x_0) = 0
$$
Then $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ wouldn't be arbitrary, meaning, you can't optimize in general both.